# How to find if my WAMP Server is 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have installed WAMP on my Windows 8, now for some reasons I need to know if it is 32bit or 64. Browsed around and looked in 'abouts' and version/licence files but couldn't find anywhere. It is WAMPServer 2.2 by the way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One easy way is to look in the process list. Bring up the Windows Task Manager. On the processes tab locate the WAMPServer process. If it is running as a 32-bit process it was say "(32 bit)" after the name. If it doesn't it is a 64-bit process.

Obviously... if you are running 32-bit Windows 8 then WAMPServer is a 32-bit process.

**Update:**
In Windows 10 there is a Platform column in Task Manager. To see it click the 'Details' tab, right-click on the header for the task list and choose 'Select Columns'. Tick 'Platform' - it is near the bottom of the list

Comment: It is 64bit Windows, that's why I couldn't figure out. Thanks 'Task Manager' helped here too!

Comment: Hi, I need to know this as well in order to repair it. As it is not running how can I find out please (on Win7-64bit)? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568835/corrupt-wampserver-how-to-recover.  Regards, Glyn

Comment: You could look at the executable with a tool: http://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows

Comment: @Rob I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit Laptop. I want to install `Ci-bonfire` can you please advise me what is the best way. I tried lot of articles. But wont work. Can you explain it from the beginning.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` suggest in its architecture section? Is it the architecture of `Wampp`?

Answer (score 5):

You can always also right-click the system tray icon and select "About".

Comment: Yes for new versions it is simply that easy.