# Corrupt Wampserver - how to recover?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

My laptop crashed this morning after which the wampmanager.ini was corrupted. I found out how to resolve that by pasting in a replacement and ensuring that this line pointed to the correct directories:

Action: run; FileName: “c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php-win.exe”;Parameters: “refresh.php”;WorkingDir: “c:/wamp/scripts”; Flags: waituntilterminated

However, I still get an error "Exception Eception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15A0. Could not execute run action: The directory name is invalid.

[image: Error Message]

I have check: “c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php-win.exe” and “c:/wamp/scripts”. I even pasted them into the address line at the top of the page to make sure and they were found.

What are my options please?

Can I run a repair?
Is it just quicker to reinstall?
If I reinstall which directories do I need to copy in order to save my database?

I do not know much about this so if you can be specific please that would be very much appreciated (e.g., full file paths where possible).

Thanks,

Glyn

I have found this:
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,71125,printview,page=1

https://superuser.com/questions/373255/wamp-not-working-on-windows-7-64bit

Now I need to work out whether I am using WampServer 32 bit or 64 bit. How do I do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, wampmanager.ini is recreated every time you run wamp. What you actually need is an uncorrupted wampmanager.tpl.

If you have a backup, replace the `wampmanager.tpl` file in `\wamp`

SECOND ANSWER:

You could try this.

Rename the old wamp folder.

Install WAMP again, using the same version of wamp Apache,MySQL.

Copy your database's from old location to new location + any website code.

That should get you back to where you were roughly.

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, And if I do not have a backup of the wampmanger.tpl do I have to reinstall? Thanks for your help, Glyn

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, Thank you very much for your help. I copied the WampServer directoy to another drive, uninstalled the WampServer and then reinstalled. Guess what! It now works and all my data is still there. I did not delete the directory first as I thought the uninstall would do that. I am now getting a connection error in my program. I will work through this before starting another question if I can not resolve it. Once again thank you very much for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Your problem will probably be related to MySQL Users. The install will have placed a new MySQL database into the wamp folder structure. Thats why I suggest the copy of `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data` from old to new. This will replace all your databases and the MySQL database as well, (Users/Passwords/Privileges/etc). Or just copy `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\mysql`. BUT OF COURSE BACKUP FIRST.

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, I realy do appreciate your follow up. The issue was to do with how my serverside code connected to the MySQL DB. Temporarily I have changed to user id to to System without any password so I could complete some testing. I will fix the user id and password this weekend. This is not an issue at this time as it is stand alone on my tablet. Once again thank you very much for your help, greatly appreciated, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happenned because I moved by mistake folder "scripts" from "*C:\wamp*" to "*C:\wamp\tmp*". I put it back and it works now.
I found this soltion looking in "**wampmanager.ini**" (*section [StartupAction]*) the directories expected to find, and I saw that "scripts" was missing.