# PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_mongo.dll

Tags: php, mongodb, dll

I'm a beginner for this. I'm trying to install mongodb driver on php.

```
Platform: Windows 8.1 64bit.
PHP 5.5.9
Apache/2.4.7
```

Followed the instruction here:http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

I've tried all php_mongo.dll file with VC11 and put in php/ext folder. and added `extension=php_mongo.dll` in php.ini file but when I tried to start apache in xampp controller I got an error.

```
    Php Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
  'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' -%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've already check my VC compilator version inside phpinfo() and it's stated there `MSVC11` with `architecture: x86`.

it would be nice if someone can help me.
Thanks. appreciate it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Make sure you download the correct .DLL for your PHP installation. Good chance you're running apache x86, so download an x86 `php_mongo.dll`. Also if you're running PHP as an Apache module, make sure you pick the `thread safe (ts)` one and also pick this type of `dll` that matches the PHP version you're running.

The versions must match or else you will get a php startup error. Find these Mongo DLLs [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows).

I did this then I got an error `libsasl.dll` not found. I simply copied the `libsasl.dll` found in my PHP installation directory to the `Apache` installation directory (where `httpd.exe` is found). Then I restarted my Apache and it worked!

Comment: The trick here is indeed to copy the libsasl.dll from the php folder to the apache binary folder

Comment: yeah. copying libsasl.dll to apache bin directory solved the problem.

Comment: @Bryan KIm can u help me to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910162/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-1-6-8-5-6-vc11-dll-in-php

Comment: it didn't help. I am still getting the error, but I can see mongo loaded in phpinfo()

Comment: "make sure you pick the thread safe (ts) one and also pick this type of dll that matches the PHP version you're running." yes!

Comment: please make sure check your php version and php_mongodb.dll file version

Comment: Is this support on php 8.2.12 WAMP on windows?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone googling this in 2017, the PECL Package has been updated and is now found at http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.2.9/windows

and use:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

instead of:

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

Answer (score 6):

Copy `C:\xampp\php\libsasl.dll` to `C:\xampp\apache\bin\`, restart `Apache` and enjoy.

Comment: it didn't help. I am still getting the error, but I can see mongo loaded in phpinfo()

Comment: It worked for me, although there was already a "libsasl.dll" available in C:\xampp\apache/bin.
I just replaced the copy from C:\xampp\php\libsasl.dll to C:\xampp\apache\bin\ and it did the trick

Answer (score 4):

If you are still having problems after doing the above, do try older version drivers instead.

That is what worked for me on for my XAMPP/ PHP 5.5 on windows 8.

Older drivers can be found here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

New drivers can be found here: http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows

You may also want to visit : https://serverfault.com/questions/563867/mongodb-unable-to-load-driver-on-php

Comment: The new drivers link at pecl mongo 1.5.5 worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is normally because we use 64 Bit supported DLL file 64 Bit system. But the wamp/xampp architecture could be 32 Bit. We need to use based on the wamp/xampp architecture not the windows architecture. So, try to find relevant version of DLL file to the wamp/xampp architecture. The solution in the below link worked like a charm to me,

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/151xpk3fkr/php-5-6-3-with-mongodb-driver-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-not-a-valid-win32-application

This link helps you to find the wamp/xampp architecture, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22454865/4874281

Comment: Yes bitnami wamp turned out to be 32bit. Can't believe that worked.

Answer (score 1):

After doing all the steps as mentioned in previous comments xampp may not be able to load the ".dll" file. Just ensure to add the path of the ".dll" file's folder to the environment variable as a system variable path.

I was facing same issue, then after adding the path of the ".dll" file's folder to the environment variable as a system variable path, it worked. It is then able to find the file.

At the end that was the only step which was stopping xampp to load the ".dll" file, although it was present in that folder. Often people miss this step as it is no where pointed out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

My PHP version is 7.2.3 x86

Go to this website and pick DLL according to php version:

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.4.2/windows

And set this in php.ini

```
extension=mongodb
```