# error while trying to set up mongo db with xampp

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am getting an error 'unable to load dynamic library, php_mongo.dll is not a valid win32 application' while trying to install mongo db extension for xampp

I have tried the same for xampp 1.8.1 and 1.8.3 but still the same.

now checking with xampp 1.8.1 php 5.4 compiler MSVC9, PHP Extension Build API20100525,TS,VC9

Really tired of this issue.

Sombody can help ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to load correct dll file for your mongo db. If your system is x86 then download dll for x86. This might help you.

[PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_mongo.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll)