# MongoDB, Windows and PHP plus wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, installation

I am using `Windows 7 x64` with `PHP 5.5.12 plus`.

I am receiving the following error:

> line 862 "extension=php_mongo.dll" and the ext_dir "extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/""

I placed `php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll` inside said directory and renamed it to`php_mongo.dll`, restarted without problems. Placed it online, also, without problems.

However it is still not installed, tried a full computer restart, neither worked, and not placed in phpinfo().

Using 1.6.10 version, will also give the same results.

EDIT: the error:

> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:10:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [18-Aug-2015 07:13:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpwEz.png image of php just pulling bullshit as usual (everything is there, tried read only and without read only.)
Apparently php cannot find ANY module, even if they're ticked on wamp's menus.

EDIT2:
After adding libsasl.dll to apache's directory following [PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_mongo.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll) instructions the error changes into:

> [18-Aug-2015 07:36:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>
> in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the thread-safe or non-thread-safe PHP build? I tried to reproduce the error on my Windows 7 build, which has thread-safe PHP installed, and it wouldn't work with the nts MongoDB driver, but the thread-safe one worked fine.

In short: Be sure to use the driver with 'nts' in the name if you're running the non-thread-safe PHP build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used both, NTS gives a "php5.dll is missing" plus the module cannot be found, however I have "Thread Safety" as "enabled"

Comment: That's frustrating... What web server are you using? Apache? Do you have the right Visual C++ redist installed? Looks like the driver requires VC9 or VC11.

Comment: I should have, VC11, if you need I can post a screenshot of phpinfo(), and it's extremely frustrating as it's also happening on my other computer. I have the 12 installed, should I install 11 instead?

Comment: Try moving the extension=php_mongo.dll to the bottom of your php.ini file, and restart php and your web server.

Comment: You can install VC11 without uninstalling VC12, and I'd recommend doing just that :)

Comment: Result is still the same. Did also install (well, repair)VC11 just in case, result is still the same.

Comment: I don't want to send you on a wild goose chase, but if it were me, I'd reinstall PHP and use the non-thread-safe version, and use the nts dll. There's a lot of discussion surrounding PHP threadedness anyway: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php)

Comment: I'm discovering the same issue. I worked on this for hours now but still no result. I'm already working with VC11. Have you found any solution?

Comment: anyone? any solution?