# Php Startup : Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll ' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am trying to install mongo driver in xampp.I put `php_mongo.dll` in ext folder of php and added `extension=php_mongo.dll` in `php.ini` file.Now I restarted the xampp and I am getting this error

> Php Startup : Unable to load dynamic library
>   'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll ' - The specified module could not be
>   found.

Please help me out with it.Am I missing any step.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php\_mongo.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll)

Comment: @danrah... Thanx a lot..It solved my problem..

Answer (score 7):

1. please visit "https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb", choose corresponding version mongodb .dll
2. use phpinfo() to check "Thread Safety" ,if "enabled" upload "Thread Safe(TS)" version ,otherwise upload "Thread Safe(NTS)"

I know my english is poor ,so I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to this link:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017
2. Create a php page and copy paste this code:

   It will give the php version.
3. Go and check the SQL Server version in your computer
4. Basis this choose the Thread Safe dll version mentioned in the page:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017
5. Download the .exe
6. Install this in the php extension path. If Xampp is installed, it is of default:
   C:\xampp\php\ext
7. Then create a .php page:
8. It should work.