# Mongodb extention 1.3.0 not installed in php 5.6.26 wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I need to install mango db PHP extension 1.3.0 with my wamp64

**WINDOWS**
Windows10 64bit

**WAMP**

apache 2.4.23 **/** php 5.6.25 **/** php 7.0

I try everything but still having issue 
- see solutions from this Q
[PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_mongo.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll/47919688?noredirect=1#comment82808055_47919688)

other drivers work fine but I need a specific driver to person some function. experts help appreciated.

**Driver I need**
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.3.0/windows

**Why I need** 
[image]

**More updates**
When I add Mongodb 1.3.0 ts version in wamp / bin / php / php 5.6.25 / ext folder it give me error. I try to fix it with copy paste solution but not worked.

[image]

Comment: Are you installing the `Thread Safe` version of mongodb. That is the one that will work with WAMPServer

Comment: It looks from your system tray like you are not connected to the internet

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, Thread Safe because of my PHP show Thread Safe Enable, well its old image but after that, I try to after connected the Internet still issue.

Will check to install with Non Thread Safe version and update here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Non Thread Safe version not working even not show the error also in PHP info not show the Mongo extension.
download from here - https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.3.0/windows

Comment: Of course not. You MUST use Thread Safe for anything you install into Apache/PHP

Comment: Did you check the error message `PHP: Syntax error, unexpected '('` and fix it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly so when I installed TS MongoDB extension 1.3.0 I got an error

"The ordinal 4694 could not be located in dynamic link library "

I used the solution that exist in above question links but not work at all :/

Comment: That sounds more like a openssl error to me. Are you using https/ssl?

Comment: Yes I use that plugin actually I try to install this on my localhost /wamp

link - https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico/blob/master/doc/installation-windows.md

Answer (score 1):

As [Cocorico is compatible with PHP 7.1](https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico/blob/master/doc/installation-windows.md#php) i would use PHP 7.1 instead of PHP5 and [mongodb extension 1.3.4](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.3.4/windows) instead of 1.3.0.

You will find here http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ most of what you need to use php 7.1 in Wamp.

Take care of TS / NTS and x64 / X86 informations for PHP and pecl mongodb extension.

Last thing don't forget to install the Microsoft VC++ packages as described in the bottom of the page.

Comment: well, let me try this and update here in my WAMP i have both PHP version :)

Comment: Well, I follow all things but still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the issue and fix it with done few more steps and Yes @Tsounabe comment help me to go further in it.

**The first step** I have php 5.6 , php 7 and php 7.1 in my WAMP server so removed 5.6 to make thing much clear but you guys should keep if you want it. Then i Select php 7.1 and right click on WAMP SERVER icon and change CLI too.

**The Second step** I already have composer so I uninstall it and install it again with .exe file and select PHP 7.1.

Then restart everything and my mongodb extention worked :)

**WAMP SERVER VERSION : 3.1.1 64bit** - http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/

**PHP VERSION 7.1.12** - You can install WAMP SERVER PHP ADDON from **ABOVE URL**

**MongoDB VERSION 1.3.4 -** https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.3.4/windows