# Windows MongoDB PHP extension not load

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, apache

I'm trying to install the mongodb extension in PHP 7.1.0 but basically the extension is not loaded by PHP (not displayed using php_info() and not throws any error, just not load), i have follow and searched too many tutorials and nothing has worked.

MongoDB 4.0.2 is installed and working as expected. PHP 7.1 is working as expected.

Steps made:

1) Download PECL compatible (PHP version and thread safety/no thread safety) mongodb driver.

2) Open /ext directory in PHP installation and put the .dll extension downloaded on it.

3) Edit php.ini file and enable the mongodb extension appending the code using (extension=php_mongodb.dll).

4) Restart Apache service.

The corresponding php.ini file is loading correclty (see print below)

I tryed use another old versions of the extension and not worked.

I have many PHP versions installed, i tryed in 5.6 too, and not worked as well.

I have tryed in other machine using PHP 7.2 and not worked, i searched too many and not found a solution, i hope some person can help! Thanks.

References:

Windows 8.1

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

All marked as blue i have tried to install, **and all downloads are made Thread Safety x64** (correspondent architecture).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, need to copy some .dll files from PHP install to Apache install, hope to help someone! [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll)