# How to install Mongodb to WAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I would like to install Mongodb driver to Wamp so according the documentation I have downloaded mongo driver from [this site](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.4.2/windows) and stored it in php/ext directory as the picture shows [image] also in php.ini extension is included like next picture shows [image] but php_error.log still shows me an error: **[07-Nov-2018 09:33:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/mongodb (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_mongodb.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0**

What am I doing wrong? Is there misssing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to restart Apache after make changes in php.ini, the architeture from .dll you have downloaded (compatible with your machine) etc, if the error persist, try this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729142/windows-mongodb-php-extension-not-load), i had a similar issue, and i needed to put some .dll files (having nothing to do with mongo .dlls, yes it is strange!) from PHP installation to Apache bin directory.. Hope it helps!

Comment: Of course I did restart WAMP after all changes. I have to look at your reference.