# Can not install doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

I want to install doctrine/mongodb but I get error:

```
Using version ^4.2 for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.2.0 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.2.1 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.2.2 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.1.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.1.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.6 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ^4.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2].
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I am using this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/installation.html#install-the-bundle-with-composer
Thank you
[https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az2Pw.png)

Comment: Which parts of that error message have you read? What have you tried to resolve that errors?

Comment: HI, yes I now I need newest doctrine/mongodb-odm but I dont know how to write or how to fix this. I need to know command. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the output composer tries install `doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` which depends on `doctrine/mongodb-odm` which requires mongodb extension version 1.5+ installed on your system.

Hint from the tutorial
[image]

So, lets go https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php#installation :)

Comment: Hi, sorr it is not woking. I am used to Flex. This command : composer config extra.symfony.allow-contrib true
and after that I used to composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle. But I ger same error.

Comment: Have you installed and enabled mongodb? What is the output `php --ri mongodb`? @VojtěchJanoušek

Comment: HI, thank you for your replay. In bash a get: vjanousek@localhost test]$ php --ri mongodb
Extension 'mongodb' not present. Now I create new project at windows and I have same issue.

Comment: try this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

Comment: Hi, I add extension for manual. Look at the first comment form me: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php I get same error and new error: composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll (Uveden├Ż modul nebyl nalezen.)

Comment: maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll