# Can not install MongoDB driver for PHP using XAMPP

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I try to install the php drivers for MongoDB on my local environment but can not get it to run.

I downloaded the latest version (an every variation of this version because I got desperate), putted the driver in the exp/ folder and updated the extension=mongodb line in the php.ini (here I tried extension=php_mongodb.dll as well)

Nothing seems to work and my apache error log logged this error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\mongodb

I wonder if it is because of the double backslashes but I have no idea where to fix it. Every other extensions is loaded normally.

My PHP version ist 8.2.12 on an x64 architecture.

Do you have any idea what the solution can be?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660534/12763954), last paragraph about libsasl.dll.

Comment: Did you also install the MongoDB Database itself. The PHP extension only connect PHP to the Mongo db, it does not replace it

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes I tried the apache/bin/libsasl.dll and have MongoDb installed.